# Setting selected value to DropDownList in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

Could someone help me with setting the selected value of the DropDownList to the database given value. I have couple of TextBoxes for which it isn't hard to set the value from the database, but what drives me crazy is DropDownList.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNaziv" runat="server" Width="430px" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Naziv") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

As far as I know, it isn't possible to set the selected item value from the code front to the DropDownList, but I was able to find out something like this (code snippet from Telerik's RadGrid documentation):

```
        protected void EmployeeDetails_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList tocs = new ArrayList(new string[] { "Dr.", "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms." });

        ddlTOC.DataSource = tocs;
        ddlTOC.DataBind();

        object tocValue = DataBinder.Eval(DataItem, "TitleOfCourtesy");

        if (tocValue == DBNull.Value)
        {
            tocValue = "Mrs.";
        }
        ddlTOC.SelectedIndex = tocs.IndexOf((string)tocValue);
        ddlTOC.DataSource = null;
    }
```

The problem is I'm using Linq-to-SQL and I'm not sure how to recreate something like the above code. This is what I currently have:

```
        protected void ddlTip_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TSEntities db = new TSEntities();

        var partType = (from pt in db.PartType
                       select new { pt.idPartType, pt.Naziv }).ToArray();

        ddlTip.DataSource = partType;
        ddlTip.DataTextField = "Naziv";
        ddlTip.DataValueField = "idPartType";
        ddlTip.DataBind();

        object Tip = DataBinder.Eval(DataItem, "idPartType");

    }
```

**One more thing I have to add that this TextBoxes and DropDownList are inside the UserControl which is being used inside Telerik's RadGrid for its EditForm.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the SelectedValue of the dropdown:

```
ddlTOC.SelectedValue = tocValue;
```

You can also do it like this:

```
ListItem li = ddlTOC.Items.FindByValue(tocValue);
if (li != null)
    li.Selected = true;
```

**EDIT**:
Included code to bind list directly to db.PartType:

```
TSEntities db = new TSEntities();       

ddlTip.DataSource = db.PartType; 
ddlTip.DataTextField = "Naziv"; 
ddlTip.DataValueField = "idPartType"; 
ddlTip.DataBind(); 

ddlTip.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(DataItem, "idPartType").ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you, that would probably be good for the code in the middle, but my scenario has LINQ-to-SQL which I believe is a bit different.

Comment: @Hrvach: What do you mean? Why won't this work for the linq-to-sql part? You have the part type id stored in object Tip, right? You should be able to do the same thing, pretty much.

Comment: Because for some reason when I'm using LINQ-to-SQL my app crashes (WebServer crash) and when I remove the part with the LINQ-to-SQL everything is fine, but without DropDownList working.

Comment: @Hrvach: It sounds like what you really need help with is the LINQ-to-SQL section of the code.

Comment: Well, what bothers me the most is that I can't load the selected values of the DropDownList in the RadGrid's EditForm. But also, for some reason LINQ-to-SQL is also causing some kind of trouble.

Comment: @Hrvach: What is db.PartType? Is that a table of some sort? Did you try changing it to db.PartType.AsEnumerable() in your LINQ query? Post some more information explaining what's happening with the LINQ query. What does the error say?

Comment: db.PartType is a table, it has only two fields; idPartType and Naziv(Name). Error doesn't say much, my WebApp just crashes and I have to rerun the WebServer (CTRL + F5) from Visual Studio 2010.

Ok, the problem is definitely when I'm trying to bind the data to the DropDownList.

Comment: @Hrvach: Do you even need to use LINQ there? You're not filtering the results; can't you just bind db.PartType to the list directly?

Comment: No, I'm not filtering the results, but I'm not sure what do you mean by binding table directly to the list. P.S. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: When I'm using DataBinding event, WebServer crashes, but when I use PageLoad() it works fine except with PageLoad I can't set the correct values from the RadGrid to the DropDownList.

Comment: Thank you a lot... Something seems to be wrong with Visual Studio or something else related to it. I'll try your code when I fix this error that's been bugging me... 

Thank you a lot once again!

Comment: @Hrvach: Yea, I don't think that the DataBinding event is the best place to do do this. I think you're list is already binding at this point, and your code keeps rebinding the list over and over again. You should bind the list on Page_Load, and set the value either OnDataBinding or in Page_Load after calling DataBind()

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
ddlTip.Items.FindByValue(tocs).Selected = true;
```